# Porcentajes en dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

tengo que poner los porcentajes de los supervivientes y fallecidos de un desastre de un dataframe.

Mi código es este

```
supervivientes=df['Survived']==1
es_superviviente=df[supervivientes]
print(es_superviviente.value_counts())
```

Me da una cantidad enorme de información y no me da la cantidad de supervivientes, el dataframe consta de 12 columnas, una de ellas es 'survived', que se comporta como un boleano con 1 para los supervivientes y 0 para los fallecidos. Hay otra columna que llama 'Name' en la que están todos los pasajeros, también valdría la columna de 'PassangersId', ya que tengo que después dividir por el total y presentar los porcentajes en una estructura de dataframe. Creo que con esto lo he explicado bien ya que no puedo poner la captura para que veáis como es el dataframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Exactamente no sé como abarcarlo, el material que tengo de pandas es escaso, si alguien me ayuda se lo agradezco

Comment: La captura del dataframe no ha salido. Y en todo caso sería mejor ponerlo como texto y no como imagen (`print(df)` te lo mostrará como texto aún en un notebook)

Comment: La captura del dataframe no es necesario para resolver el problema, tu comentario no ayuda. Si solo entras a preguntas para indicar que esta mal o que esta bien pues no estas contribuyendo en nada

Comment: @jonas, si quieres tener unicamente los porcentajes puedes hacer esto: ```df.survived.value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict()```. Esto te dara un diccionario con esta estrucctura: ```{1: cantidad_porcentual, 0: cantidad_porcentual}```

Comment: @jonas y esto te dara una mejor vista: ```df.survived.map({1:'sobrevivientes',0:'fallecidos'}).value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict()```, ya que la salida es asi: ```{'sobrevivientes': 0.571, 'fallecidos': 0.428}```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero para que la salida fuera con un formato de dataframe, no lo consigo y he visto líneas de código por ahí, parecidas a las de mi ejercicio que si lo consiguen, por ejemplo he visto ésta

Comment: pasajeros=df({'Survived':[1,0]})
(pasajeros['Survived'].value.counts()/pasajeros['Survived'].count())*100

Comment: Pero me dice que el dataframe no es invocable como error

Comment: `df["Survived"].sum()` te daría la suma de esa columna ¿no sería eso el número de supervivientes? El de fallecidos sería `len(df)` menos el número de supervivientes.

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo de código, pongo un par de ejemplos para calcular el porcentaje.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [
    [1, 0, "Nombre 1"],
    [2, 1, "Nombre 2"],
    [3, 0, "Nombre 3"],
    [4, 0, "Nombre 4"],
    [5, 1, "Nombre 5"],
    [6, 1, "Nombre 6"],
    [7, 0, "Nombre 7"],
    [8, 0, "Nombre 8"],
]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["PassengerId", "Survived", "Name"])
>>> df

    PassengerId Survived Name
0   1           0        Nombre 1
1   2           1        Nombre 2
2   3           0        Nombre 3
3   4           0        Nombre 4
4   5           1        Nombre 5
5   6           1        Nombre 6
6   7           0        Nombre 7
7   8           0        Nombre 8

>>> 100 * df.loc[df.Survived == 1].shape[0] / df.shape[0]
37.5

>>> 100 * df.Survived.sum() / len(df)
37.5
```